# "Sandbox" for using multiple instances of a javascript lib

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using a js lib, which will create a global variable "AV" used everywhere in a WebApp.
But I want to create a "sandbox"(not actually a strict sandbox because of no secure concern) to use multiple different "AV"s in one WebApp.

I wrote a wrap for browser below and it works.

```
var AVContexts = {
    App1: null,
    App2: null
}

var ContextLoader = function (appId, appKey) {
    this.AV = null;
    this.runInThis = function (script) {
        eval(this.script);
        this.AV.initialize(appId, appKey);
    }
    this.loadContext = function (appId, appKey) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'js/av.js',
            dataType: "text",
            context: this
        }).done(function (data) {
            this.script = data;
            this.runInThis.call(this);
        }).fail(function () {
            console.log('failed');
        });
    }
    this.loadContext(appId, appKey);
}

AVContexts.App1 = new ContextLoader(
        "[appid]",
        "[appkey]"
);
AVContexts.App2 = new ContextLoader(
        "[appid]",
        "[appkey]"
);

// Do something
var TestObject = AVContexts.App1.AV.Object.extend("TestObject");
var testObject = new TestObject();
testObject.save({foo: "bar"}, {
                success: function (object) {
                    alert("AVOS Cloud works!");
                }
            });
```

But when I move it to nodejs. An error occurred at

```
this.runInThis.call(this);

ERROR: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined
```

Any idea?

Comment: this in your case is `$.ajax` object, you'll have to save the context using `var that = this;` and then use `that` instead of `this`

Comment: On a side note, you're trying to use jQuery's ajax function inside of node? I don't think that's going to work...

Answer (score 0):

You should cache the "this", like this:

```
var me = this;
```

before you use $.ajax. and then,

```
$.ajax().done(function() {
    me.runInThis.call();
});
```

If you want to know the reason,

run

```
console.log(this);
```

before

```
this.runInThis.call(this);
```

you will know the reason.

Comment: Your answer is right but you should explain why `this` is different in the callback scope, and not `You will know the reason`.

Comment: Thanks, I want to explain clearly, but I am not good at English... so, you know, explain this question need a lot of words.